# effect plots: how to add legend, change text size and add significance levels?

Tags: r, legend, glm, lme4, significance

Me and some friends need to 'upgrade' a GLM and LMER plot.
we need to add the significance levels, change text size and legend position.

how do we do this in the "allEffectsplot"??

[image: this is what we have now...]

it needs to look somewhat like this graph (the right image is the correct one): [[image: we need the graph looking like this one2]]

Comment: Please include code you used (including packages used) along with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question.

Answer (score 3):

**changing the position of the legend:**
I just want to answer the question in case any other comes here and want to try what worked for me.
I don't know which package the there is used to make the effect plot but I had the same problem and adding  `key.args = list(space="top"))` to my code worked.  To make the effect plot I used the effect package.

Here is an example of my code:

```
library(effects)
library(car)
library(MASS)
library(splines)
library(lattice)

plot(Effect(focal.predictors = c("income","age", "country"), 
    mod = mymodel, xlevels = list(age = 50:80), latent = TRUE),
  rug = FALSE, axes = list(grid = TRUE), multiline=TRUE, 
      colors = c("color1", "color2", "color3", "color4", "color5"), 
     lattice = list(layout = c(5,1), key.args = list(space="top")))
```

just add number of colors according how many categories you have. I had 5 categories of income, so I wrote name of 5 colors I liked. If you want the legend at the right side of the plot you can just write "right" instead of "top".

Comment: Does this get you the significance stars/p-values?

Comment: No but changing the position of the legend.. did I misunderstooth the question?

Comment: The question isn't great -- it includes too many separate questions.  Your edit makes your answer better.

Comment: I now added a title that specify my answer is only for the legend